# Loop through colours array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to give each div a different background colour. Here is my current code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uy2FX/2/

```
var imgColours = ['#FCCF94', '#C4C9E5', '#ADE3D6'];

for (i=0; i < imgColours; i++) {
        $('.img').css({backgroundColor: imgColours[0]});
}
```

However, I'm not quite sure where this is going wrong. I understand that's probably too simple to work, but in my mind it makes sense. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `i < imgColours;` should probably be `i < imgColours.length;` and `{backgroundColor: imgColours[i]}` should be `{"backgroundColor": imgColours[0]}`. But even so, that would happen so fast you'd only see the last color.

Answer (score 1):

There are some relevant errors in your code.

This is probably what you wanted to do:

```
// V1 : Basic
var imgColours = ['#FCCF94', '#C4C9E5', '#ADE3D6'];
for (var i=0; i < imgColours.length; i++) {
    $('.img:eq('+i+')').css({backgroundColor: imgColours[i]});
}
```

But if you want to get a random color from your array, for any number of divs, and also optimise your jQuery code a bit for better performance:

```
// V2 : random colors
var $imgs = $('#boxes1').find('.box'),
    imgsCount = $imgs.length,
    coloursCount = imgColours.length;

for (var i=0; i < imgsCount; i++) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * coloursCount),
        color = imgColours[rnd];
    $imgs.eq(i).css({backgroundColor: color});
}
```

Or, if you want to loop through the colours following the order of the array, just change the loop:

```
// V3 : sequential colors
// Add V2 variables here

for (var i=0; i < imgsCount; i++) {
    var color = imgColours[i%coloursCount];
    $imgs.eq(i).css({backgroundColor: color});
}
```

UPDATED FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Uy2FX/12/

For some very basic tips on jQuery selectors performance: http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `imgColours.length`

The for loop has no idea how long the array is otherwise

Edit: What's the point in this for loop if you end up using `imgColours[0]` anyways? If you want to loop each color, use `i` instead of `0`.

And either way, this will not achieve a different background per div.

Try selecting by className (I'm going to use vanilla.js because it's simple)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
for (var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var color = imgColours[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgColours.length)]; //get a RANDOM color change me if needed
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've got the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/Uy2FX/6/ I'd like to let the  colours go through the total array of blocks, rather than just stop after 3. Would that be possible using the % operator? (i % something.length)

Answer (score 0):

You are always assigning `imgColours[0]` to EVERY div. I think what you are looking for is `imgColours[i]`

You will also need to use imgColours.length to tell your loop how long the array is.

You are also grabbing all HTML elements with the class of `img`, so this will change all of them each time.

To grab each element separately, you can use the CSS `nth-of-type` selector. Basically you can just do something like

```
$(".img:nth-of-type(" + i + ")")
```

Comment: Aaah, thanks. What should I use to grab each img individually?

Comment: @tmyie I updated my answer with the the `nth-of-type` selector.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var ec = 0;
var i = 0;
for(ec; ec < elements.length; ec++, i++) {
   elements[ec].style.backgroundColor = imgColours[i];

    if(i == (imgColours.length - 1)) i = -1;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y2dq3/